# Datadog Monitor Setup

Tags: datadog

I have one log line e.x: "File Size is 32"

I want to setup a log level monitor which triggers when log would be "File Size is 33" or "File Size is 34" or "File Size is 35" and so on. Basically, I want my monitor to trigger when integer value in log message will be greater than 32 (>32) . Is it possible to setup monitor like that or to apply operations on text inside log message ?

Can someone please help around this ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I am trying to figure out if operations can be applied to text in log message. Till now I have tried using parsing rule.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: Edited. I hope its understandable now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Datadog log searching allows you to make queries against numeric values.

1. Send the log to Datadog by setting up the Datadog agent to tail your file: https://docs.datadoghq.com/agent/logs/?tab=tailfiles#custom-log-collection
2. Set up a log parser to pull out that file size field as an attribute: https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/log_configuration/parsing/?tab=matchers (parser rule would look like `File size is %{integer:file_size}`)
3. Turn the log attribute into a facet so it is searchable: https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/explorer/facets/#create-facets
4. Set up a log monitor to alert if that facet is greater than whatever value you want: https://docs.datadoghq.com/monitors/monitor_types/log/#monitor-creation